# "Meet up" vs. "meet" vs. "hook up"

Tags: differences, american-english, phrasal-verbs

What's the difference between *meet up*, *meet* and *hook up* as a synonym of *meet up*?

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/) has the following definitions:

> - *to meet up*: to see and talk to someone familiar or someone you do not know: *"Let's meet up for drinks after work."*
> - *to hook up*: to meet someone and spend time together: *"I was traveling alone, but then I hooked up with another woman about my age."*

These definitions are really similar.
What is the subtle difference between these three words?

Comment: related: [what is the difference between “hook up with” and “have sex with”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87377/what-is-the-difference-between-hook-up-with-and-have-sex-with)

Comment: related: [His brother “hooked” him up with this bachelor party](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36134/his-brother-hooked-him-up-with-this-bachelor-party)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hook up* in common American parlance (among the under forty set) [means](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hook-up) to engage in sexual acts.

*Meet* (in this context) and *meet up* mean [meet](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/meet), that is, connect at a time and place.

Comment: Yeah, you don't want to say "hook up" if you mean "meet up", that's just awkward.

Comment: Two people can also _hook up_ on Facebook. A drug peddler might _hook me up_ with my weekly supply of crack cocaine.

Comment: Depends on context. _Hooked up_ can also mean _formed (or joined) a team_, like in [these instances](http://books.google.com/books?id=8JRHnCMUVb8C&pg=PA317&lpg=PA317&dq=%22hooked+upr%22&source=bl&ots=qS7RIjOuqp&sig=IXgVUKWxbrfMt9ogHRsJyASLwJs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bxKBUMrNBu6GyQHT-4GICQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22hooked%20up%22&f=false). It doesn't always have a sexual connotation.

Comment: what's the difference between this hook up (without sexual connotation) and meet up?

Comment: [This](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/hook-up) says two people begin doing something together. Two other suggestions by coleopterist and J.R. I would avoid it because of ambiguity unless you were explicit about the nature of the *hook-up*.

Comment: hoop up doesn't necessarily mean "to have sex", although it can mean that.

Answer (score 0):

As the question wants to know the differences in meaning when hook up is taken as a synonym for meetup, I'll ignore the sexual act connotations of hook up (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hookup_culture).

'Meet' has a stronger likelihood to mean 'meet for the first time,' and is slightly more likely to refer to a couple or small number of people gathering. 'Meet up' emphasizes a group coming from different places to the same place. The latter is strengthened by the meetup.com service which has turned meetup into a noun, sometimes amongst strangers bonding together over a common interest in politics, technology or other shared interests, often on a regular basis that engenders a community.

'Meet' is in a slightly higher register of language and formality than 'meet up', and 'hook up' is lower than both. Hook up can also mean one person putting a second in touch with a third for the purposes of getting something.